# Android - Resize camera image in kilobytes

Tags: android, image

I'm capturing an image using camera (And it is saved in the pictures folder). I want to resize it before convert it into String and upload it into a server. I have a constraint that the maximum file size should be about 850 kilobytes.

I have a knowledge about `Bitmap.compress` method which only reduces the image quality using a percentage. But the difficulty in that is that the different devices might produce images with different sizes. So I'm unable to use static percentage to reduce the size.

I have the image url and it can be converted to a Bitmap. Can I reduce the size of an image for any value under 850 kilobytes?

Comment: Have you done anythings from your end then please post it ?

Comment: I haven't done anything to resize it yet. I was looking for an solution and I found out the Bitmap.compress will reduce the size. But it does not solve anything regarding my problem. And I have observed many solutions with reducing the size and width, but all I want is to reduce the size (in kilobytes). Thanks!

Comment: Get the bitmap, check the size of the bitmap, then you know approximately how much you need to compress it. Compress it, check the size and send it to the server? Checking size and scaling have several answers and questions on SO.

Comment: u can do it by scaling width and height. check `Bitmap.Options` `inJustDecodeBounds` `inSampleSize`

Comment: How do I do it by resizing the size as I don't know for sure that which size gives me the amount of kilobytes I want..?

Comment: i think w * h /1024 ≒ bitmap kb. calc original size and downsampling some time then we'll done.